# Postman scripting: how to decode token

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I'm using postman with scripting.

1. *First*, I perform a request to retrieve a **oauth token**.
2. *Then*, inside the 'Test' tab, I'm using postman scripting to use the received token to set a global (postman) variable.

Additionally, I would like to **decode the token**, because I want to use information inside the token to set them as variables. The token **payload is base 64 url** encoded.

How do I do that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I found this piece of code on the net. It uses **atob** sandboxed script to decode base 64 encoded payload

```
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
const payload = jsonData.id_token.split('.')[1];  // Assuming the JWT is in id_token
const parsed = JSON.parse(atob(payload));
pm.environment.set('user_id', parsed.user_id); // Assuming user_id is in the payload
```